# Sails / Waterline: Find by associations

Tags: sails.js

How to can I find by collection association and get all results with that query?
Example:

POSTS MODEL

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
      title:        'string',
      content:      'string',
      coverImage:   'string',
      owner: {
          model: 'user'
      },
      tags: {
          collection: 'ContentTag',
                 via: 'posts',
            dominant: true
      }
    }

};
```

TAGS MODEL

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
      name: 'string',
      posts: {
          collection: 'post',
          via: 'tags'
      }
  }
};
```

**I need:**

```
*POSTS.find( { 
   where: {
     tags: 1 
   } 
}).populateAll() // All Post with ID tag 1*
```

**Without use:**
*TAGS.find({id: 1})*

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can do it the way you'd want. What you can do, however, is something like:

```
TAGS.find({id: 1})
.populate('posts')
.then(function(tags) {
    var posts = tags.posts
    // 'posts' now has all posts associated with tags with id 1
})
```